# Equivalent of ReisizeEnd event User Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have made a custom task pane using a user control.
Every time I resize it I raise a method called `SuspendDrawing` the reason I do this is because the buttons on my custom task pane flicker when I resize it therefore I need to suspend it. I add these buttons using the designer

This works like a treat but then I need to call a method called `ResumeDrawing` when the user stops resizing however I don't know what event I should use to call the `ResumeDrawing` method as there is no `ResizeEnd` event for a user control.

Any suggestions would be appreciated as I'm out of ideas.

My code is as follows

```vb
Public Property Resizing As Boolean

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SendMessageA", ExactSpelling:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError:=True)>

Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Public Shared Sub SuspendDrawing(ByVal target As Control)
    SendMessage(target.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub ResumeDrawing(ByVal target As Control)
    ResumeDrawing(target, True)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub ResumeDrawing(ByVal target As Control, ByVal redraw As Boolean)
    SendMessage(target.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0)
    If redraw Then
        target.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SideBarPowerPoint_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
     SuspendDrawing(Me)
End Sub
```

My Custom Task Pane

```
    Dim taskPaneView = New PowerPointCommon.SideBarPowerPoint
    sideBarTaskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneView, " ")
    If sideBarTaskPane.Visible = True Then
        sideBarTaskPane.Visible = False

    End If
    sideBarTaskPane.Visible = True
    sideBarTaskPane.DockPosition = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight

    sideBarTaskPane.Width = 100
```

Comment: You are probably trying to solve the wrong problem.  Why are your controls flickering?  We need to see that code.

Comment: Have you set the `.DoubleBufferered` property of the container? Or set the container style with `.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)`?

Comment: A bit more information please.  Is this a run-time or design-time issue?  Is the control resizing in response to its containing form being resized or is some other resize mechanism?

Comment: @Jimi I tried using the double buffer it didn't seem to work.`Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)`. It's like it's repainting my buttons every time I resize it.

Comment: Then something is interfering with the normal drawing procedure. Try to clean up everything, use docking/anchoring, comment out code in the OnPaint event if present. I have no idea why you are using SendMessage. It's just piling up and it's synchronous. Enable the `.DoubleBufferered` property of the UserControl and, eventually, the container form.